# What is the data type returned from the function utxosAt scriptAddress

Tags: plutus

I want to use the value returned from the function utxosAt scriptAddress. What is the value that this function will return ? Is it going to be in a list , json etc.....

Answer (score 1):

A `(Map TxOutRef ChainIndexTxOut)` see [here](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/playground-common/html/Playground-Contract.html#v:utxosAt).

A good example can be found in the pioneer program of how to utilize that
function:

```
{...}
utxos <- Map.filter (isSuitable pkh) <$> utxosAt scrAddress
{...}
where
   isSuitable :: PubKeyHash -> TxOutTx -> Bool
```